# Reading from a server in a list/details Fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using this code/concept :

[Android Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html)

What I am wanting to achieve is, on item selected (as seen below), I want to send the item to the server, have it process on that side (which I can do) and retrieve the `String` that is sent back and use that string to update the details part of the list/details fragment. Is there anyone that help me in achieving this through some code?

My code so far is as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements HeadlinesFragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener 
 {

XMLCreator x = new XMLCreator();
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.news_articles);

    // Check whether the activity is using the layout version with
    // the fragment_container FrameLayout. If so, we must add the first fragment
    if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) 
    {

        // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
        // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
        // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
        if (savedInstanceState != null) 
        {
            return;
        }

        // Create an instance of ExampleFragment
        HeadlinesFragment firstFragment = new HeadlinesFragment();

        // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an Intent,
        // pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
        firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

        // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();

    }

    postToServer();
}

public void postToServer()
{
    new Connection().execute();
}

public void onArticleSelected(int position) 
{
    // The user selected the headline of an article from the HeadlinesFragment

    // Capture the article fragment from the activity layout
    ArticleFragment articleFrag = (ArticleFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment);

    if (articleFrag != null) 
    {
        // If article frag is available, we're in two-pane layout...

        // Call a method in the ArticleFragment to update its content
        String Day = "";
        Day = Ipsum.Headlines[position];
        Document doc;
            try 
            {
                doc = x.createDoc();
                Element tutor = doc.createElement("Query");
                tutor.appendChild(x.createDay(doc, Day, "GetSessionByDay"));
                doc.appendChild(tutor);
                String s = x.getStringFromDocument(doc);
                //connection.sendData(s);

                                  //Want to send and receive strings here
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            articleFrag.updateArticleView(position);
        }
    else 
    {
        // If the frag is not available, we're in the one-pane layout and must swap frags...

        // Create fragment and give it an argument for the selected article
        ArticleFragment newFragment = new ArticleFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ArticleFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);
        newFragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();
    }
}

public class Connection extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> 
{
    // the I/O streams that will be receiving/sending data from/to the
            // server
            private ObjectOutputStream output;
            private ObjectInputStream input;
            private String message = "";
            private Socket client;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        // IMPORTANT: this method is synched with UI thread, so can access UI
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {

        try 
        {
            client = new Socket("10.111.1.1", 5001);

        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            output = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            output.flush();
            input = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        do 
        {
            try 
            {
                message = (String) input.readObject();

            } 
            catch (ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException) 
            {

            } catch (OptionalDataException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        while (!message.equals("SERVER>>> TERMINATE")); 

        try 
        {
            output.writeObject(message);
            output.flush();

        } catch (IOException ioException) 
        {

        }

        // sleep a bit, so this task isn't over before it starts
            try 
            {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                Log.e("TASK", "Error sleeping in CalculateTask");
            }

        // return value to be passed to onPostExecute of task initiator
        return message;
    }



    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... progress) 
    {
        // IMPORTANT: this method is synched with UI thread, so can access UI

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {
        // IMPORTANT: this method is synched with UI thread, so can access UI
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // update UI
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Create a method `postToServer()` in the `MainActivity` to execute the `AsyncTask`. Call this method inside the `OnItemClickListner` in the fragment

```
((MainActivity)getActivity).postToServer();
```

In the `Fragment`, create a method `updateUI(String response)` which handles the UI updating and call this method from your parent `Activity` when the `AsyncTask` is finished. Call this method in the `OnPostExecute()` of the `AsyncTask`;

Comment: So I call the updateUI(String response) in my onListItemClick method? and that will then update the UI in the fragment it is linked to?

Comment: i have modified the answer, please check

Comment: When I add the updateUI(String response) method, I run into a problem. My fragment is static, so I can't reference it in my main activity. Otherwise I'm sure the answer you've provided would solve my problem.

Comment: why are you making it static, any particular reason? Its best to keep the fragment in a different java file.

Comment: I've changed my code to have each fragment in each separate java file. Is there a way I could possibly get it to you for you to look at? I'm probably not seeing my problem because of how frustrated I am.

Comment: add the code to the question, then i could help you more

Comment: It is too much to add to comment :( Using this code as a basis:http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html
and want to send and receive data in the onArticleSelected method in the MainActivity which extends FragmentActivity

Comment: modify the question itself and add the code over there

Comment: I've modified the question to include the code I am using.

Comment: you have to call `articleFrag.updateArticleView(position);` in the `OnPostExecute()` of the `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 0):

Just call to server from your Fragment, like method `getData()`, inside that, I think you have to implement `AsynkTask`. When you get response of that request in `DoInBackground()`, just pass that to `onPostExecute()` and use that response and update your UI whatever you want.

Comment: So something like: @Override 
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
{
    showDetails(position);
    string s = getData();
}

public String getData()
{
String s = new Connection().execute().get();
}

Then in dobackground I return a string? Would that work?

Comment: Yes, it will work, but pass your data from onPostExecute() method, after completion of your request, response.